# printf to USB-CDC on FreeRTOS

Tags: c, printf, freertos, cdc

I'm working on a STM32 Cortex M4 with a FreeRTOS running.
I try to redirect my `printf` to the USB CDC output but it seems like my implementation isn't thread safe. A loop of `printf('test')` prints

```
ettttt
tttetttttttst
ttetettttttettttttettttttt
ttttttttttttt
t
tttttttttetttttttstttt
tettttttttttttt
t
tttttttetttetttttttett
ttttettttttetettetttt
ttttttttt
ttetetttt
t
ttt
```

I use the following `putchar` prototype

```
PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE {
    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)&ch, 1);
    return ch;
}
```

Additionally I use the `printf-stdarg.c`, at least I thought I do. But when I change

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, format );
        return print( 0, format, args );
}
```

to an empty implementation

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
{
        return 0;
}
```

it still prints to the console as before. So it seems like it's not actually using the implementation from `printf-stdarg.c`.
My idea was to surround the `print` call with a mutex.

Comment: Have you seen this: [How to make printf/sprintf/strtod thread safe](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/April_2018/freertos_How_to_make_printf_sprintf_strtod_thread_safe_44d2ceb8j.html)?  If you read through, there is a github project with a thread safe `printf`.  I am not sure how well it works, but you can certainly take a look.

Comment: Yes I've seen it, but I thought because I'm using `printf-stdarg.c` there's no use of `malloc`. What github project did you find?